# Could not find a storyboard named 'X' in bundle NSBundle But I already have

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

this is my first q. here. I saw that lots of ppl getting this error time to time but mine is kinda different. Im getting this error but I already have a storyboard called 'MusicList' I checked couple of times there's no misspelling or something. And as u can see I tried to debug to know is there any other problem except this part of the code but no, I just can't do my storyboard exact same name with my storyboard. Am I missing something ? PS: I deleted my main.storyboard and also in info plist and build phases part.

[Part1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aqsAV.png)
[Part2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ykZrD.png)

Comment: Is MusicList.storyboard inside the bundle? Open the Storyboard, on the right panel, File Inspector, "Target Membership"

Comment: Think not i believe, think im getting this error cuz of this but not sure ? Can u tell me how can i check it ?

Comment: I updated my comment

Comment: Oh no, its shows unchecked box called MusicBox(my workspace name). But It's passive atm. Can't change it.

Comment: If you create a new one, you can't add it to the target (when creating)? How did you create your app?

Comment: @Larme I was tryin to practice apple's mvc like pattern(so there's no outlet in my controller. I also tried to use custom specific storyboard for my controller in this example: MusicList.storyboard and MusicListViewController) I built it from scratch, 1 app, 1 framework(this one like network layer MusicBoxAPI). I also tried to use Builder pattern, u can see App group for it. I was trying to separate Scene delegate manipulation. Everything was fine so far now i got this strange error. Like bug or something. Maybe cuz of xcode 14 update dunno actually. I hope I could clear to you sir.

Answer (score 0):

Follow the steps below:

1. Right-click on your Storyboard and select `delete`
   [image]
2. There will be a confirmation prompt, select `Move to Trash`
   [image]
3. Now Right-click on your file directory and select `New File`
   [image]
4. Select Storyboard from the list and press `Next`
   [image]
5. Give the proper name of your storyboard and hit `create`
   [image]
6. Now select your Storyboard and select your File inspector from the right panel and ensure that the tick mark is there on the target.
   [image]
7. Now select your Project name, select the project target and change the Main Interface option by your newly created storyboard.
   [image]
8. Now clean (`shift + command + k`) the whole project and build it.

Comment: I tried ur solutions sir(I moved to the trash, create a brand new one, give the proper name like u told, choose the right bundle), but at 6th step Target Membership still grayed out(disabled) so I couldn't choose.

Comment: Can you share the screenshot?

Comment: [Here is](https://imgur.com/a/Lqn16DO) @Tulon